# nginx: how to set up server blocks to allow subdomain

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, openresty

I have openresty running on my aws instance (Instance A) and the ip address of the server is already tied to the domain name `myapp.john.com`.

My app is running on another aws instance (Instance B) within the same private network. It has private ip address of `192.42.56.87` and the app is running on port `:80`.

I want to set up my openresty / nginx such that when visiting `prod.myapp.john.com`, nginx directs me to `192.42.56.87:80`. And when visiting `test.myapp.john.com`, nginx directs me to another instance (Instance C) running the test version of my app, say on `192.xx.xx.xx:80`

Below are code in (Instance A):

Main config file `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` is defined as:

```
# Main NGNX Config File
#user www-data;
worker_processes  auto;
pid logs/nginx.pid;

error_log  logs/error.log  info;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    keepalive_requests 100000;

    resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s ipv6=off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    gzip  on;

    # Include all the sites for the domain
    include /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sites/*;

}
```

`/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sites/prod.myapp.john.com` is defined as:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name prod.myapp.john.com; // this does not work; but "myapp.john.com" works
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name prod.myapp.john.com; // this does not work; but "myapp.john.com" works

  ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.john.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.john.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.42.56.87:80/;

    expires 0;

    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

  }
}
```

Now, in chrome browser when I visit `prod.myapp.john.com`, there is no response at all since the request never get to my Instance A;

However, if I change

`server_name prod.myapp.john.com`

to

`server_name myapp.john.com`

it works and the web page gets rendered.

Why?
How can I include more site files in `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sites/` and set the `server` blocks in config correctly to provide more subdomains on my site?

Comment: What is the error? Is it a 404 by nginx, a 500 by nginx or could it be that you simply did not configure the sub domains in your DNS? If you just add `myapp.john.com`, DNS will not give anything back for `*.myapp.john.com`...

Comment: Silly me. I assumed that I had a wildcard subdomain DNS record, but I don't.